# How can I migrate empty message by using Kafka MM2?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to migrate from the source cluster to the target cluster using Kafka MM2(Mirror Maker 2).
This is a situation in which there are empty messages occupying an offset due to [transactions in Apache Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) in a specific topic (partition : 1) in the source cluster.
Since MM2 replicates all messages by default, I thought that empty messages would also exist in the target cluster, but it wasn't.
By duplicating empty messages, I want to make the offset of all topics of partition 1 of the target cluster the same as the source cluster. How can I set MM2?

(The contents of the capture are confirmed by ui that there are empty messages occupying offsets 1, 3, and 5 in the source cluster. When this is sent to the target cluster, the empty message disappears, and I hoped that the offset of the message, which was 0, 2, 4, would remain the same, but it turns into 0, 1, 2.)

source kafka version : 2.8.0
target kafka version, MM2 : 3.4.0

my mm2.properties

```
clusters=from, to

from.bootstrap.servers=broker1A:19091,broker1B:19092,broker1C:19093
to.bootstrap.servers=broker2A:29091,broker2B:29092,broker2C:29093
from->to.enabled=true
from->to.topics=.*
from->to.groups=.*

replication.policy.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNxaz.png)

If there is a filter, I tried this to see if the filter would filter out empty messages by adding

```
from->to.filter.exclude=
```

Comment: I think you might want to upgrade to 3.5.1. If you look at the release notes since then, there's been mm2 improvements